# In pyspark, what is the difference between spark.read() and spark.readstream()?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

In PySpark, what is the difference between spark.read() and spark.readstream()?

I am trying to understand the various options to read data in Databricks. I came across these two functions on spark read() and readstream() but could not find information on when to use which and how they differ from each other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They serve different purposes:

- `.read` is used for batch data processing, when you read the whole input dataset, process it, and store somewhere. If you add new data and read again, it will read previously processed data together with new data & process them again.
- `.readStream` is used for incremental data processing (streaming) - when you read input data, Spark determines what new data were added since last read operation and process only them.  There are different types of streaming data processing - continuous, when your program runs all the time and processes data, or batch-like, when it starts, figures out what new data is available, and finishes after processing is done.  It's regulated by the [triggers](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#triggers).